# Could not find asset polymer|lib/default_build.dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I upgraded  my Dart to Dart 1.7_dev4.5

My application does not run anymore and now I have the following stack trance

```
Could not find asset polymer|lib/default_build.dart.
e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-dev\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub_generated\lib\src\log.dart 183       
exception e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-dev\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub_generated\lib\src\entrypoint.dart 75  Entrypoint.acquireDependencies.<fn>.<fn>.join0.join1.join2.<fn>.join3.<fn>.<fn>
dart:isolate   _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
```

My build.dart is:

```
export 'package:polymer/default_build.dart';
```

Is the default_build.dart no longer relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Your build file should still be fine. 
Try killing `pub serve` and try again. If that doesn't help, try `pub cache repair`.